# Should pivot tables have more columns (many to many relationship)

Tags: mysql, database-design, table, relations

I'm currently thinking about how to organize my tables, and I have some information that I'm not sure were should be, one of them is the quantity of a food in a refrigerator

[image: Database model]

---

Is it right if I add quantity in `refrigerator_has_food` table? Or should this table only have foreign keys?

Comment: Is it important out of which fridge did the user take food?

Comment: You should have the table if there is only one refrigerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no restrictions on data stored in the pivot table. The simplest case of two IDs establishes only qualitative relations between fridges and foods: `this food is stored in this fridge`. If you add the counter you just turn the qualitative relation into the quantitative one: `this many units of this food is stored in this fridge`.

On the opposite side you have to control the counters and remove any row having counter dropped to zero to avoid silly logic `yes, we store zero units of this food in this fridge`.